# Why are mongoose references turning into IDs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

According to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, if I set a ref property to an object, and not an ID, when getting it, I should get back an object and not an ID.  I'm referring to this part of the page:

```
var guille = new Person({ name: 'Guillermo' });
guille.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  story._creator = guille;
  console.log(story._creator.name);
  // prints "Guillermo" in mongoose >= 3.6
  // see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-release-notes
```

Here's my sample code:

```
var T1schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    otherModel:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"T2"}
});

var T1 = mongoose.model('T1', T1schema);

var T2schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String},
});

var T2 = mongoose.model('T2', T2schema);

var t1 = new T1();
var t2 = new T2({email:"foo@bar.com"});
t1.otherModel = t2;
```

Now when I refer to t1.otherModel, it's just an ObjectId, and not a T2.  For example:

```
console.log(t1.otherModel.email);
```

prints undefined instead of "foo@bar.com".  Any ideas why?  Note I'm using Mongoose 3.6.18 according to it's package.json.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your expectations here just don't match what mongoose does. The schema is a way of saying "model M's property P will always be of type T". So when you set a value, mongoose uses the schema definitions to cast the set value to the type the schema requires. Here's a little REPL session. Note setting a number property with a string value casts it to a number, but trying to store a boolean in a number field just ignores the errant value.

```
> var mongoose = require('mongoose')
> var schema  = new mongoose.Schema({prop1: Number})
> var Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema)
> var m  = new Model
> m.prop1 = 42
42
> m.prop1
42
> m.prop1 = "42"
'42'
> m.prop1
42
> m.prop1 = false
false
> m.prop1
42
```

So when your schema says something is going to be an ObjectId, if you give it a model instance, mongoose immediately converts it to an ObjectId in preparation for a write to the database, which is the common case. Normally if you just set that model instance, you don't need to get it back out of the parent model before saving the parent model to the database.

So the model instance getter defined properties are always going to return something compatible with the schema, and `populate` has to do with loading refs from the DB, but for whatever reason mongoose just doesn't work the same comparing a `.populate`d instance with a non-populated instance. I can see why this is confusing and perhaps unexpected/disappointing though.

Comment: Thanks, though seems like a bug to me.  The docs say updating a ref will save the id, but the getter will return the object.  Seems odd that this only works after you've saved the object.

Comment: Mongoose isn't going to take a synchronous ref assignment operation and make a DB query to get the object so you have it in memory. There's no callback here anyway. That's what it would need to do to convert the id to a model and mongoose only does DB IO when you invoke one of the async functions.

Comment: The database isn't involved at all in my example.  I'm expecting the set/get to be reflexive.  If I call set on a ref property with an object, I'm expecting the get to return what I just set.  According to the Mongoose docs, this is the expected behavior (in the section I quoted).  The only difference between my example and theirs, is that they are working with an object that was loaded from the DB, and mine is working with a new object.  Specifically they call set _creator = guille, and then the next line they call get _creator and get back an object, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is normalizing the instance to match the `Schema`, which specifies that `otherModel` is an `ObjectId`.

```
otherModel:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"T2"}
```

So, Mongoose treats `t1.otherModel = t2;` the same as:

```
t1.otherModel = t2._id;
```

The `ref` isn't used until [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) is called (either directly on the document or in a query), which needs both objects to be saved:

```
t2.save(function (err) {
    t1.save(function (err) {
        console.log(t1.otherModel);
        // 7890ABCD...

        t1.populate('otherModel', function () {
            console.log(t1.otherModel);
            // { email: 'foo@bar.com', _id: 7890ABCD..., __v: 0 }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yet Mongoose is not treating t1.otherModel = t2; as t1.otherModel = t2._id; after a populate call, which in my opinion is inconsistent behavior.  Either treat them the same pre & post populate or don't.